# Append jquery inline datepicker inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How can I append multiple inline datepickers inside a loop? My try to achieve this functionality is [here](http://jsbin.com/hezapiteya/1).

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){

var line = $('<span class="date" name="test" ></span>');
     $('#myForm').append(line);
     line.find('.date').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: Code should be added in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` ***IS*** the `.date` element, but `find()` finds descendant elements, what you really want to do is just use `line` directly, there's nothing to find

```
line.datepicker();
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/vudenuboga/1/edit?html,css,js,output)